# Socket.IO Qt implementation

Tags: c++, qt, sockets, web, socket.io

I want to have QT working with Socket.io. Firstly, I want to know if it's possible to work with socket.io without a node.js server and do the server with Qt.

I need to pass data from my Qt application to a web page. So, socket.io looks good. The problem is with the C++ implementation (https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-cpp) which use Boost librairie and I have some problems to add it to my project.

So I see the poco project (https://github.com/himynameschris/socket.io-poco) that don't use Boost librairie, and so, seems to be great and easier to add. But i have some problems to compile the lib with CMake and Visual Studio 2015.
The CMake generation looks like to work great, I have a solution generated with multiples project.

As said :

> Under Windows, you will need to open the main Poco solution, build the ALL project, and then build the INSTALL project.

I build the "**ALL_BUILD**" first. I have some error with Poco librairie... And then the same thing of boost libairie.

So anyone  hasn't an implementation using just QWebSocket that works with Socket.IO ?
Or any solution else...

Comment: Is there any special reason why you don't want to use the Qt socket classes?

Comment: Because sokcet.io doesn't work with QWebsocket.